# Why do I get blurry pictures when I take a lens attachment off?

Tags: lens, troubleshooting

I bought a Canon D3300 bundle. This is my first dSLR. It came with a couple lenses. On Easter, I decided to use a wide angle lens to get all the action. Now I can't use my camera without this lens because it is so blurry. I have tried putting it on Auto, and restarting it. For now I'm just not getting it. I want to use my 18-55mm lens. Please help.

Comment: Is your other lens on manual focus? Look on the side and see if the switch is on M or A.

Comment: Nikon D3300 I'm assuming. Canon does not have a model D3300 that I'm aware of.

Comment: Is your wide angle lens a separate lens or an adapter you screw onto the front of your 18-55mm lens?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, this just happened to me and the last answer scared me until I realized that I had left a piece of (the bottom half of) the new lens attachment I'm using, on the camera! :) LOL 
So **check again!** (I know this is a year later for the original question) :).

But yea, **you might have done like me and just need to REALLY unscrew that bottom half of your new lens attachment off of the camera too. 
After I did this, my lens worked perfectly no blur etc. just like before.**

This post did make me aware though to be mindful of how I attach and use my lens attachments with my lens, and to just be mindful of everything previously mentioned in the other answer.
Hope this helps everyone. I had to share this relieving discovery. :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might have damaged the 18-55 lens by twisting on the "wide angle" lens when your 18-55mm lens was set to autofocus. The force of twisting the screw-on "wide angle' adapter onto your lens with the focus motor connected may have damaged your lens' focus motor to the point it can no longer focus on distant objects when the wide angle lens is not attached.